# Tensorflow: Cannot allocate buffer larger than kint32max for StringOutputStream

Tags: pandas, machine-learning, tensorflow

I am trying to run a Tensorflow Linear logistic regression model on a dataset with ~10 million rows and 50 columns.

When I run the same model on a subset of this, i.e. ~ 6million set, the model runs fine. But when it tries on this 10 million set, it throws up the following stack trace and exits

```
    [libprotobuf ERROR google/protobuf/io/zero_copy_stream_impl_lite.cc:173] Cannot allocate buffer larger than kint32max for StringOutputStream.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tensorflow_up.py", line 70, in <module>
    m.fit(input_fn=train_input_fn, steps=200)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/util/deprecation.py", line 280, in new_func
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/estimators/estimator.py", line 426, in fit
    loss = self._train_model(input_fn=input_fn, hooks=hooks)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/estimators/estimator.py", line 984, in _train_model
    _, loss = mon_sess.run([model_fn_ops.train_op, model_fn_ops.loss])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/monitored_session.py", line 462, in run
    run_metadata=run_metadata)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/monitored_session.py", line 786, in run
    run_metadata=run_metadata)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/monitored_session.py", line 744, in run
    return self._sess.run(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/monitored_session.py", line 883, in run
    feed_dict, options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/monitored_session.py", line 909, in _call_hook_before_run
    request = hook.before_run(run_context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/basic_session_run_hooks.py", line 340, in before_run
    "graph.pbtxt")
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/graph_io.py", line 67, in write_graph
    file_io.atomic_write_string_to_file(path, str(graph_def))
ValueError: Unable to convert message to str
```

This is the snippet of code that is relevant:

```
m = tf.contrib.learn.LinearClassifier(feature_columns=[location, master_source, device] + realValues, model_dir='~/')
m.fit(input_fn=train_input_fn, steps=200)


results = m.evaluate(input_fn=eval_input_fn, steps=1)
```

Am I missing something here? The memory stats look fine when the program is running.

Comment: Are you using [queue input](https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/threading_and_queues), or embedding the dataset in the graph? If the latter, you may want to switch over to queues to speed up graph construction and checkpoint writing in addition to working around this error. As is, it looks like your whole training dataset is getting logged along with the graph.

Answer (score 0):

[Installing Tensorflow from sources](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_sources) solved the problem in my case.